What happens if you go through the door for transphobes?
In the Super Mario World romhack Super "Sonic Saves the World" World, at the end of the Act 4 stage "In This House," there are two doors and a message box that says the following:

Transphobes>
Continue through the door on the left.
Non-Transphobes>
Use the door on the right.

The door on the right leads to the end of the stage with a banner saying "TRANS LIBERATION NOW" in the colors of the transgender pride flag. What happens if you go through the left door?

Screenshot from Barb Plays "Super 'Sonic Saves the World' World" Part 4

I'm getting an error clicking on the first link. Also, what exactly is this world, and what is it trying to accomplish?

Considering that the "non-transphobe" lets you continue and end the level, the "transphobe" one will likely send you to the beginning of the stage or to a section that leads to a different message at the end of the stage.

@Joachim It's a mod for Super Mario World by the creator of Celeste that adds new levels.
